# Ubuntu as a router in between windows serveer 2003 and xp client

Tags: router

Is it possible to configure Ubuntu as a Router. WAN is connected to Windows server 2003.
And clients having XP should connect to  internet via ubuntu.

thanks in advance,

sp

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a standard Ubuntu PC as a router.  It will be better and with more practical.

To see a complete  tutorial go to [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=926001)

Comment: Hello Mitch. Thanks for the nice tutorial link. I am trying to implement the same.

Comment: Hi Mitch. I want install Samba on ubuntu to access Windows server 2003. can you advice any good link - similar to above. thanks in advance, sp

Comment: See [How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-samba-server-on-ubuntu/), and [Unixmen](http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/)